# Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.example.or.dancers.Info

Tags: java, android, firebase

I am trying to insert info to a Firebase Database , and I am Getting the above error.

Full stacktrace:

```
04-16 02:42:14.218 6214-6214/com.example.or.dancers E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.or.dancers, PID: 6214
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.example.or.dancers.Info
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zze(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zzb(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqi.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
  at com.example.or.dancers.Settings$1.onDataChange(Settings.java:187)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbmz.zza(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbnz.zzYj(Unknown Source)
  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzboc$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7229)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

My Object Model:

```
package com.example.or.dancers;

public class Info {

public String key;
public String infoName;
public int data;

public Info() {
}

public Info(String key, String name, int data) {
    this.key = key;
    this.infoName = name;
    this.data = data;
}
}
```

the retrieveData function:

```
public void retrieveData() {



    database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Info d = data.getValue(Info.class);

                if(d.key.equals(info.key)){
                    info =d;
                    return;
                }

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }


    });

}//retrieveData function.
```

I stuck at this , and because of that I cant move on. 
Any help would be appreciated.

get value:

```
 public Object getValue() {
    return this.zzbXv.zzUY().getValue();
}

public Object getValue(boolean var1) {
    return this.zzbXv.zzUY().getValue(var1);
}

public <T> T getValue(Class<T> var1) {
    Object var2 = this.zzbXv.zzUY().getValue();
    return zzbqi.zza(var2, var1);
}

public <T> T getValue(GenericTypeIndicator<T> var1) {
    Object var2 = this.zzbXv.zzUY().getValue();
    return zzbqi.zza(var2, var1);
}
```

Comment: data.getValue(Info.class) returns a long value

Comment: well, `DataSnapshot.getValue()` seems to return a value of object `Long` while your class `Info` isn´t an object of type `Long` , so you should show us the code of `getValue()` method...

Comment: So quick , thank you 

and 

    
added on the main thread

Comment: Please post the JSON (as text, no screenshot) at the location that `database` points to. You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). Without the JSON, all anyone can do is repeat the error message in different words.

Comment: and what is `zzbXv.zzUY().getValue(var1);` ? have you ever tried it with casting like `Info d = (Info)data.getValue(Info.class);` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should debug to find what values did you pass to your Info object. Because of this error related to convert Long to Info:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.Long to type com.example.or.dancers.Info
```

Comment: I tried with Log to print what the data gives me but It's still get crashed.